# jQuery menu not working on server but working properly on localhost

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

In https://harissonsbags.com jquery menu not working but the same code is working properly on localhost.

This is the code snippent.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $("#mobile-menu").mmenu({
        classes: 'mm-light'
    }, {
        selectedClass: "active",
    });
});
```

I ran this code on javascript console on the website.

```
jQuery("#mobile-menu").mmenu({
        classes: 'mm-light'
    }, {
        selectedClass: "active",
    });
```

Then the menu accordion is working. While page loading the javascript is not executing.

Any suggestion would help.

Comment: does the console tell you anything?

Comment: while execuing the script in console it is showing this message.
[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive.

Comment: I am seeing the error `Cannot set property 'onkeyup' of null` and `Cannot set property 'onkeydown' of null`, post the code where you call these

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Because of the error below javascript was not executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page has some JavaScript errors pertaining to this code below:

```
var el = document.getElementById("zipcode");

el.onkeyup = function(evt) {
    var fieldValue = el.value;
    if(fieldValue.length == 6) {
        codeAddress(fieldValue);
    }
};
```

Fixing this should fix your menu as this code is not in an document ready tag it is running first and causing all other JavaScript to not execute.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to load jquery library before all other plugins

[image: Not able to see jquery version]

[image: No jquery file]